# No blinking cursor in HTML5 input type date

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Please help with a focus indication problem in Chrome and Edge (Firefox seems to work fine).

This html will display an html 5 date picker input element. It defaults with focus, and will have the mm highlighted, indicating that it has focus. However, when I click away and then back in, the control outline goes darker, indicating it has focus, but it does not highlight the mm portion of the date, until I start typing. How do I fix this? This seems to be broken in Chrome and Edge, but works in Firefox.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="date" autofocus/>
    </body>
</html>
<style type="text/css"> 
  input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    cursor: pointer;
  }  
</style>
```

**Initial view after start up (good):**

[image]

**After clicking away (good):**

[image]

**After clicking on the control (bad):**

It is focused, apparent by the darker border, but it's not clear one can type. There is no highlighted part, or blinking cursor. How can it make it so that when one clicks on the control and it regains focus, it looks like the initial state, with the month highlighted, indicating it is ready for input?

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: These behaviors and appearance are dictated by browsers. If you want them to be identical everywhere, you have to use the library.

Comment: ..."you have to use the library", what library? Also why would it highlight mm on initial autofocus, but not when regaining focus?

Answer (score 0):

You want a blinking cursor, which I don't think is possible with a HTML5  date format input. But you can show it's focused. Why not just apply a style to it for when it's focused?

```
<style>
 input.date-picker:focus {
   border:1px solid #f00;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: It will already show that it's focused, see screenshot in the OP. But why wouldn't it highlight the mm portion of the date, indicating it's ready for input? How do I make it do that, after re-focusing?

Answer (score 0):

The different behaviors in different browsers are by design. If you want to have the blinking cursor or highlighted part in all browsers, you can use [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default).

Sample code is like below. The blinking cursor will show when you click, and the highlighted part will show when you double click:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="mm/dd/yyyy">
```